# How to update backup URL in app? Lets say for example Main URL is missing. How the back up url will accesible?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

How to update backup URL in Android App. Lets say for example Main Url is missing or not accessible how the android app will switch to back up URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen this package [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly)

> Polly is a .NET 3.5 / 4.0 / 4.5 / PCL library that allows developers to express transient exception handling policies such as Retry, Retry Forever, Wait and Retry or Circuit Breaker in a fluent manner.

You could use it to catch the `WebException` then retry or switch out the URL.

Here is an example from the blog post below:

> In this example, we will try connecting to our service five times, with an exponential wait of 2, 4, 8, 16, and 32 seconds between tries. This should give the device a chance to reestablish its network connection and continue the request to the api.

```
conferences = await Policy  
  .Handle<WebException>()
  .WaitAndRetry
  (
    retryCount:5, 
    sleepDurationProvider: retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt))
  )
  .ExecuteAsync(async () => await getConferencesTask);
```

Here is a blog post talking about [Resilient network services with mobile Xamarin apps](http://arteksoftware.com/resilient-network-services-with-xamarin/)